# Convexity properties of $ \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_{S_1(0)} \Vert x -y \Vert d \mathbb{\lambda}^1(y) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $S_1(0)$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For a point $x \in B_1(0)$ define the function $f(x)$ to be $$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_{S_1(0)} \Vert x -y  \Vert d \mathbb{\lambda}^1(y) $$

i.e for a point $x$ we are computing the distance to every point on the circle and integrating. The function is obviously rotational symmetric and has a minimum at $0$. What can be said about convexity of this function?

I have tried to compute the function explicitly, therefore I have tried to solve the integral

$$ f(t)= \int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{1+t^2 - 2t \cos(x)} dx $$

for values $t \in [0,1]$. This is the value of the function at a point x=(0,t) and by symmetry therefore the value of any point with $\Vert x \Vert =t$. I have not been able to solve this integral. Does there exist an analytical solution?

Comment: There is solution but it involves elliptic integrals.

Comment: Do there exist formulas for the derivative of elliptic Integrals? If that would be true, one could try to compute the hessian of $f((x,y))=f(\Vert (x,y) \Vert)$.

Comment: There are but they involve elliptic integrals again.

Comment: Considering the answer you accepted, the question should be renamed, since you obviously did not need an analytic expression for the integral

Comment: I will rename the question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to deal with elliptic integrals to prove the convexity of our function.

For any $z$ in the unit disk, let 
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1} \|z-x\|\,dx \tag{1}$$
the average distance from the unit circle. Quite obviously, $f(z)$ is a continuous function, hence to prove its convexity it is enough to prove its midpoint-convexity, but
$$ f(z_1)+f(z_2)\geq 2\,f\left(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right) \tag{2}$$
just follows from the definition $(1)$ and the triangle inequality in the form
$$ \|a\|+\|b\|\geq 2 \left\|\frac{a+b}{2}\right\|.\tag{3}$$

---

As an alternative, the analytic function defined on $(-1,1)$ by
$$ g(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+t^2-2t\cos x}\,dx $$
has a remarkable property: it is an even function and every coefficient of the Taylor series at $t=0$ is non-negative. Convexity is a straightforward consequence.
$$ g(t) = 1+\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{t^4}{64}+\frac{t^6}{256}+\ldots \tag{4} $$
Since $f(z)$ is a radial function, we may use $(4)$ to provide lower bounds ($\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$) for the hessian matrix eigenvalues, too.

Comment: By the formulation "What can be said about convexity" I meant whether the function is $\lambda$-convex, i.e. $f(z_1) + f(z_2) \geq 2 f\left(\frac{z_1 +z_2}{2} \right) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \cdot \Vert z_1 - z_2 \Vert ^2/2$ which means that the eigenvalues of the hessian are bounded below by $\lambda$.

Comment: @Near: for such a task, I think my $(4)$ is more than enough: $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ is a lower bound for the eigenvalues of the hessian.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting $$1+t^2-2t\cos(x)=(1-t)^2+2t\big(1-cos(x)\big)=(1-t)^2+4t^2 \sin^2\big(\frac x 2\big)$$ we then find that $$\int \sqrt{1+t^2-2t\cos(x)}\,dx=2 (1-t)\, E\left(\frac{x}{2}|-\frac{4 t}{(1-t)^2}\right)$$ where appears the [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the second kind.

Then $$f(t)=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+t^2-2t\cos(x)}\,dx=4 (1-t) E\left(-\frac{4 t}{(1-t)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on $E\left(-\frac{4 t}{(1-t)^2}\right)$? As far as I understood from Wikipedia, you mean the Elliptic integral of the second kind. However it is not defined for negative values.

Comment: @Near, why do you think it's not defined? See for example for $t=0.25$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2B0.25%5E2-2*0.25+Cos%5Bx%5D%5D,%7Bx,0,2+Pi%7D%5D)

Comment: @Near. Could you tell how you thought that it is not defined ? May be some misunderstanding somewhere ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it's probably $k^2$ vs $k$ interplay

Comment: @YuriyS. You are totally right ! Always the same story; now I remember. Thanks.

Comment: Using your formula in the answer one has $$f(t)=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+t^2-2t\cos(x)}\,dx= (1-t) \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{2t }{1-t} \right)^2 \sin^2(x/2) } dx$$ which is not an elliptic integral of second kind, since the sign does not agree compare to $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(x/2)}$ the original definition from wiki. Therefore I do not understand what the elliptic integral of second kind with negative values is.

Comment: It is a question of notation, using $k$ or $k^2$. Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html

Comment: Okay so from the formula from mathworld we get $$ E(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt {1 - k^2 \sin^2(x)}dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt {1 - (-k)^2 \sin^2(x)}dx = E(-k)$$ Is that correct?

However as I pointed out in my last comment one has $$ E(-k)=  E(k)= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt {1 - k^2 \sin^2(x)}dx \neq \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt {1 + k^2 \sin^2(x)}dx $$ But the integral you computed in your answer would be of the last type.